# How do I pass a variable/parameter to big.NewInt()

Tags: go, math, numeric, factorial

The following code snippet is failing to compile on `N := big.NewInt(n)` with the following error:

> cannot use n (variable of type int) as int64 value in argument to
> big.NewInt

```
func Factorial(n int) *big.Int {
    var result = new(big.Int)
    i := new(big.Int)
    N := big.NewInt(n)
    for i.Cmp(N) < 0 {
        result = result.Mul(i, result)
        i = i.Add(i, new(big.Int))
    }
    return result
}
```

If I pass an int64 literal (i.e., `N := big.NewInt(1)`), it works.  But I need a way to convert an int64 *variable* or *parameter/argument* to a `big.Int`.  What am I doing wrong?  Does Go not support this at all?

Comment: convert `n` to the type needed, i.e. `N := big.NewInt(int64(n))`

Comment: You can use https://pkg.go.dev/math/big#Int.MulRange to find the product of numbers from `[1..n]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is because the https://pkg.go.dev/math/big#NewInt function takes an `int64` value as the argument and not an `int` type. Do the required type conversion as

```golang
N := big.NewInt(int64(n))
```

Moreover the computation logic can very simply written as

```golang
func Factorial(n int) *big.Int {
    result, one := big.NewInt(1), big.NewInt(1)
    bigN := big.NewInt(int64(n))
    for bigN.Cmp(&big.Int{}) == 1 {
        result.Mul(result, bigN)
        bigN.Sub(bigN, one)
    }
    return result
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/A-H-y10OwBb